# Why is Eclipse/JSP parsing my JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat

I have a JSP page which doesn't actually have any server tags in it so its basically an HTML page.  But, my work is in love with JSP so I set it as a .jsp file.  Anyhow, Tomcat is under the belief that my JavaScript is in fact Java code and tries to parse it.  I get a nice big error on the screen saying its not a real function, etc.  Could anyone tell me why its doing this?  Code below...

```
...
<script>

    $(function() {

        $.dragAndDrop({
            dom: {
                fileList: '#fileList tbody',
                contextMenu: '#fileContextMenu',
                dropzone: '#dropzone'
            },
            templates: {
                file: '<tr><td>${fileName}</td><td>${$.dragAndDrop.getDate()}</td><td>${$.dragAndDrop.parseSize(size)}</td></tr>'
            }
        });

    });

</script>
...
```

The error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(22,42) The function getDate must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
```

Comment: Well you have `${$.dragAndDrop.getDate()}` and `${...}` marks expressions for evaluating by JSP.

Comment: That's the problem.  Thanks :p  I had the understanding that JSP tags were <% %> but since I never use them I didn't really know.

Comment: It was introduced in JSP 2.0 I think.

Comment: You are right about JSP 2.0. I think that it was introduced along with Java EE 5. @Felix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`${}` marks expressions for evaluating via JSP](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html). As you say you don't use any JSP, you can disable the expressions language by adding

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>
```

to your page.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely the `${` notation

Try replacing this code `${$`

with something like this `$' + '{$`

or `$<%='{'%>$`

I don't know if there is a proper way to escape that,, but what I just gave you should work.

See Google for more information. The top result looks good but I could not find how to do a proper escape: http://www.google.com/search?q=jsp+dollar+sign